# add a constant float to each value in a dictionary

Tags: python

Say I had a dictionary, containing float values and I wanted to add a specific float such as 0.1 to each value in the dictionary, how would I go about doing this

{1:0.1, 2:0.2, 3:0.3}

I would want the new dictionary to be

{1:0.2, 2:0.3, 3:0.4}

I know how to do this with a list but I have no clue how to do it with a dictionary

Comment: Just beware the [normal oddities of floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/10077).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict comprehension. Basically iterate over the `items` and add `0.1` to each value.

```
data = {1:0.1, 2:0.2, 3:0.3}
data = {key: value + 0.1 for key, value in data.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two current answers are fine, but both create a new dictionary.

Of course, you could always *update* your existing dictionary (e.g. named `d`):

```
for k in d: 
    d[k] += 0.1
```

Which (for clarity) is the same as (explicit `.keys()`):

```
for k in d.keys(): 
    d[k] += 0.1
```

Note that this *will not* work or do what you expect:

```
for v in d.values(): 
    v += 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```py
data = {1:0.1, 2:0.2, 3:0.3}

result = {k: v + 0.1 for k, v in data.items()}
print(result)
```

This prints:

```py
{1: 0.2, 2: 0.30000000000000004, 3: 0.4}
```

which contains some (unavoidable) floating point rounding error.